# Анимация движение цвета

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать анимацию, где желтый цвет двигается слева на право до половины.

```css
.Suppy{
text-align: center;
font-size: 50px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="Suppy">Что то</div>
```

Comment: Кажется, вам нужно писать сюда - https://www.fl.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внешний вид поправите под себя

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 253, 20, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 253, 20, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  transition: left .7s;
}

.wrapper:hover:before {
  left: 0;
}

.Suppy {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="Suppy">text</div>
</div>
```